# access html label using keyboard and make it readable using screen reader software

Tags: html, accessibility

currently I am using the anchor tag to make a label accessible by keyboard and readable using screen reader software (Jaws or thunder any of them).

for example the solution what i have found is the below mentioned:
instead of using :-

```
<label for="I am label">I am label</label>
```

I am using:-

```
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">I am label</a>
```

I want some alternative way where i don't have to provide anchor tag for label and the label should be accessible using keyboard and it should be readable by screen reader software...

Comment: why do you even use a "non-pointing" anchor for a label? i mean why need a label "keyboard friendly" when labels are supposed to be used together with an input element to be keyboard friendly.

Comment: Agreed with @Joseph; question is unclear. `label` elements are used in conjunction with `input` elements that are part of the keyboard tab order.  When the associated input gets focus, the label will be read by the screen reader. What else is supposed to happen?

Comment: It sounds like OP is unclear about how screenreaders work: users can tab from item to item and the screenreader will read the items out, but screenreaders also have an internal review cursor that allows the user to traverse *all* items on the page, even those not keyboard tabbable: this allows screenreader users to read headers and regular paragraph text, for example. Anything that is 'actionable' - links, buttons, and so on, still needs to be tabbable, but more so for sighted keyboard-only users, not specifically screenreader users.

Comment: By the way, the label for=... attribute should be the ID of the control that the label is for; it should *not* be readable text.

Comment: Sorry for partial data, But the "label" what I am talking about is one which is placed for the "table" not for "input" element, so I need some way so I can make a "label" readable as the focus using keyboard on it is not happening hence screen reader s/w does not read it.

Comment: Labels are never used on anything other than an INPUT element.  Screen readers will usually ignore any LABEL which does not have a corresponding INPUT.  Please provide a full code sample; maybe that will make it clearer what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can cheat a bit and use the tabindex attribute to make a table cell so you can tab to it.  However, tabindexes take a lot of maintenance-- you have to update them every time you add a new element to your page that belongs in the tab order.

Semantically, you should be using the `<caption>` element to label a table, but you will not be able to tab to the `<caption>` element either.  You can put your title in a `<th>` element, and tab to that if that's what you really want.  Keep in mind that this isn't as semantically good as using `<caption>`, because a `<th>` designates the heading of a row or column, not a whole table.

Here's an example where you can tab to an `<input>` element, which is correctly labelled with a label element, as the commenters suggest, and then to the table cells, which are ordered by the tabindex attribute.  I tested this example in NVDA.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Screen Reader Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
<input id="firstName" type="text" />
<br />
<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Fruit Prices</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th tabindex="3">Apples</th>
        <th tabindex="4">Oranges</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td tabindex="4">$0.50</td>
        <td tabindex="5">$1.00</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Sources:
Tabindex http://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/tabindex#spec

Caption tag http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_caption.asp